# How to get the INBOX data in gmail through python scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I need the data from my gmail inbox,

In spider where and how I should put the credentials of my account. and how to scrap those data.

Answer (score 3):

Don't "scrap" - use IMAP, or even POP3, instead.

Python provides the [imaplib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html#module-imaplib) module for IMAP. You can enable IMAP or POP3 on your gmail account as described in [Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en#ts=1665018).

If that is not to your liking, there is also an API (many actually). Here is the "official" [REST API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/gmail/v1) and a [quick-start guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-python).